# Is that possible to update multiple procedure and function definition in EDMX file C# DB first approach

Tags: c#, visual-studio, edmx, db-first

I have to update many procs and function in edmx, and I don't want update 1 by 1 in Model browser and also don't want to re-create edmx , So is there any possible solution there, i can update multiple proc or function in edmx file in one go.

Comment: is any update? Please check if my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following to the followings to update multiple proc or function in one go.

First, please right click the edmx file and choose the `update model from database`.

[image]

Second, If you want to add the new procedures, you can click Add and choose the correspond stored procedure.

[image]

If you want to update the existed procedure, you can click Refresh and choose the stored procedure.

[image]

Third, you can see the correspond method in the dbcontext.cs file.

public virtual ObjectResult<TestProcedure_Result> TestProcedure(Nullable age)
{
var ageParameter = age.HasValue ?
new ObjectParameter("age", age) :
new ObjectParameter("age", typeof(int));

```
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<TestProcedure_Result>("TestProcedure", ageParameter);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<Pro1_Result> Pro1(Nullable<int> age)
    {
        var ageParameter = age.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("age", age) :
            new ObjectParameter("age", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Pro1_Result>("Pro1", ageParameter);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<string> Proc2(Nullable<int> score)
    {
        var scoreParameter = score.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("score", score) :
            new ObjectParameter("score", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("Proc2", scoreParameter);
}
```

Finally, you can use the following code to get the result by using the stored procedure.

```
 using (var db = new StudentContext())
            {
                var result = db.TestProcedure(20);
                foreach (var stu in result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(stu.Name);
                }
            }
```